# Batman and Joker comic where they are compared to tarot cards and Batman gets stuck under a statue

Tags: dc, comics, batman, episode-identification

In which comic issue does Batman try to stop the Joker from robbing some kind of artifact at a museum or auction house ? Throughout the entire comic, both the Joker and Batman are compared to certain tarot cards, with similarities between their personalities and functions being described.

Towards the action/climax scene, the Joker traps Batman under a huge totemic statue but Batman manages to escape. The artstyle was maybe around the 1970s or 1980s ? I'm not entirely sure about the timeframe, though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[A Clash of Symbols](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Detective_Comics_Vol_1_617)
Detective Comics #617
July 1990

> He exits for a moment, but then returns to sit as the woman deals out her tarot cards. Batman takes a card. It is "Le Mat" -- The Fool and Holy Madman. Batman asks if she can find him in her crystal ball. As the two gaze at the magical orb, he goes into a deep thought, concentrating back to three years ago when he confronted the Joker when he pulled a heist at the Star Gallery.
> ... when the two arch enemies confronted, Joker got the upper hand by knocking a pillar on top of Batman.

Comment: That's the one. I recognize the phrase "Le Mat".